# SVG sprite icon background position appears off in newer version of Chrome

Tags: css, google-chrome, svg, sprite, background-position

I am using a `background-image` SVG sprite, and everything looks great on my versions of Safari, mobile Safari, Chrome, Firefox, Opera, IE, etc. However, the background positions aren't displaying correctly for a few of my co-workers who have a newer version of Chrome (I know one of them is using Version 35.0.1916.153 on Mac, some were using a different newer version on Windows).

Here's what it looks like in my version of all browsers:
[image]

Here's what it looks like in some newer versions of Chrome:
[image]

HTML:

```
<span class="icon icon--chat"></span>
```

CSS:

```
.icon{
    background:url(data:image/svg+xml;base64,[data]);
    font-family:sans-serif;
    background-position:top left;
    background-size:cover;
    display:inline-block;
    width:100px;
    height:100px;
    padding:0;
    margin:15px;
    cursor:default;
}

.icon--chat{
    background-position:0 4%;
}
```

The exact same code worked correctly in my co-workers' browsers when I put it on JsFiddle and Codepen, but here it is anyway: http://jsfiddle.net/HgR2N/

Here are a few things I have tried that have not fixed the issue:

- changing the background image from a data-URI encoded SVG to a
  regular .svg file
- using pixels for `background-position` instead of percentages
- adding `font-family:sans-serif;` (i read somewhere that that might fix it - no idea)
- removing margins, `box-sizing:border-box;`, etc.

Please let me know if you have any ideas about what might be causing this issue and how I might be able to fix it -- thanks!

Update: I updated my Chrome to Version 35.0.1916.153, so now my co-worker and I are using the exact same version of Chrome for mac and hers are messed up and mine are still fine...

Comment: Perhaps you should report it as a bug: https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/list and click on the New Issue button

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Update: I added `preserveAspectRatio="none"` as an attribute on the svg tag in the svg file, and that fixed it! More info here: http://www.yootheme.com/support/question/6801?order=modified

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. I fixed it by setting the `background-size` to exact values (not using `auto`).
I originally defined the size of my svg sprite like this:

```
.icon {
    background-image: url("sprite.svg");
    background-size: 4em auto;
}
```

I changed it to

```
.icon {
    background-image: url("sprite.svg");
    background-size: 4em 99em;
}
```